# Ошибок нет, бот не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как Вы, наверно, поняли, я - новичок и пытаюсь по всяческим урокам написать хоть что-то И суть в том, что в cmd все работает как надо, но вот при создании бота - появились проблемы. А точнее - просто ничего не работает и ничего не отвечает. Сама cmd после запуска кода просто висит и ничего не делает, а бот не отвечает от слова совсем. Как это можно исправить?

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config


import telebot

owm = OWM('токенытокены')
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токенытокены", parse_mode= None)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer =  ' В городе ' + message.text + " Сейчас " + w.detailed_status 
    answer += " Температура сейчас примерно " + str(temp)

    if temp < 20:
        answer +=" Прохладно, возьми с собой куртку"
    elif temp >20:
        answer +=" Жарко, можешь идти в футболке "
    else: 
        answer +=" Холодно крч, надень куртку, толстовку, возьми с собой все вещи из большого шкафа и подумай, а надо ли оно тебе? "

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Не работал с этой библиотекой, но, полагаю, вы должны вызвать `bot.reply_to`. Посмотрите [этот](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/echo_bot.py) пример.

Answer (score 1):

Как не странно, но я не вижу функции:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
```

Ваш бот работает, но вы просто не отправляете ответ пользователю.

Comment: Почти все заработало, осталась только проблема вот в этом:
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
В строке 
`answer =  ' В городе ' + message.text + " Сейчас " + w.detailed_status() `

Comment: Замените строку на "answer =  f'В городе {message.text} Сейчас {w.detailed_status}'"